# absolute positioning of :before in tables vs divs

Tags: css

I'm adding a pseudo-element with `:before` and position it absolutely to its parent which can be a table or a div. For design purposes the parent also has to have a 20px border.

wwhy are firefox and IE inconsistent and treat the positioning of the pseudo-element differently in the table?

Please have a look at my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nerdess/Ns5GZ/9/) or the code below.

Tested with **IE10**, **Chrome29** and **FF23**.

HTML:

```
<div>i am a div</div>

<table>
<thead>
    <tr><th>header 1</th><th>header 2</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr><td>entry 1</td><td>entry 2</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table,
div {
   border: 20px solid yellow;
   position: relative;
   margin-bottom: 30px;
   height: 50px;
}

table:before,
div:before {
   background: red;
   content: " ";
   position: absolute;
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 10px;
   height: 10px;    
}
```

Comment: Absolutely positioned elements might not behave the way you'd expect inside table elements in FF.

Comment: Not sure if this would work for your purposes, but you could try outline instead of border on elements. For example: outline: 20px solid yellow;

Comment: @D.Alexander nice idea but no, it has to be a border as i also apply a border-radius :(

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be an issue with how Firefox handles absolutely positioned elements within tables. Can you try wrapping the div and table inside their own relatively positioned parent divs?

Check this [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/eFOLula/9/).

**EDIT**: In cases where the html structure cannot be modified, try giving the elements `box-sizing: border-box;`.

This [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/AjeDeVo/1) seems to work in Chrome, FF & IE on my machine. Let me know if it isn't rendering, and I'll give it another shot.

Comment: also nice idea unfortunately the html structure is set and i cannot change it. i am working with this chrome css hack now http://mahaveersingh.wordpress.com/2010/10/31/css-chrome-fix-chrome-alone-css-hack/ even though chrome is doing it right and all the other browsers (FF, IE) wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be that `:before` works good with just table less layouts on FF. There is some information on MDN which might be helpful.

> Although the positioning fixes in Firefox 3.5 do not allow content to be generated as a separate previous sibling (as per the CSS spec stating "The :before and :after pseudo-elements elements interact with other boxes... as if they were real elements inserted just inside their associated element."), they can be used to provide a slight improvement on tableless layouts (e.g., to achieve centering)

when I added `display: block` to the table element and removed the fixed height, it is working fine.

```
table,
div {
    border: 20px solid yellow;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    display: block;
}

table:before,
div:before {
    background: red;
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    display: block; 
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;   
}
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ns5GZ/12/)

For more information, go through [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3a%3abefore).